# preg_replace with similar values

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am working on a mentions system and I have run across a problem, when I am looping through and changing the mentions to links, it will replace similar ones such as @tom and @tom123 with the same link to /tom/ instead of individual.

I have tried using regex and preg_replace however I am also checking to see if the username actually exists, so I am just wondering if there is a way I can prevent it from happening.

```
$tweet = "@wayne how are you? @wayne123 is cool but are you?";

        preg_match_all('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $tweet, $matches);
        $i = 0;

        foreach( $matches[2] as $value ) 
        {   

            if ( $db_query )
            {
                $tweet = str_replace("@" . $value, "<a href=\"/user/$value\">@$value</a>!", $tweet);
            }               
        }

        echo $tweet; // outputs: hi <a href="/user/wayne">@wayne!</a> how are you? <a href="/user/wayne">@wayne!</a>123 is cool but are you?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have tried with regex before but it continues along the line and updates the others before I am even able to check to see if they are a valid user

Comment: Can you post the code for your `$db_query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first time through your loop @wayne123 is replaced with @wayne so it can't find a match for the second time through the loop.

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with back references.

```
$tweet = "@wayne how are you? @wayne123 is cool but are you?";
$pattern = '/(^|\s)@(\w+)/';
$replacement = '<a href="/user/$2">@$2</a>';
print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tweet);
```

in `$replacement` the `$2` is replaced with the match of the second set of parenthesis `(\w)`

Note that `(\w)` is the shorthand for `([a-zA-Z0-9_])`

Comment: Yes, however with that code it will change all of them even if the username doesn't exist, that is how I was originally doing it

Comment: Okay I see what the `if ($db_query)` is there for now. In that case replace `str_replace("@" . $value, ` with `preg_replace('/@'.$value.'\b/', ` The \b defines a word boundary and therefore @wayne won't match @wayne123

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add too much detail there! The db_query essentially checks to see if the name exists, thank you that works nicely now.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of:

> $tweet = str_replace("@" . $value, "@$value!", $tweet);

You should use:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/@' . $value.'\b/', "<a href=\"/user/$value\">@$value</a>!", $tweet);
```

Answer (score 0):

add a space?

```
$tweet = str_replace("@" . $value." ", "<a href=\"/user/$value\">@$value</a>! ", $tweet);
```

preg_replace is more usefull

Comment: Whilst it works, it is not ideal as what if the tag is put at the end of a message? I agree preg_replace is much more useful but getting it to work how I want it is a real pain!